# calling a nonstatic function in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am confused how to call a function defined in a class inside another function defined in that same class. Here is what I have done:

```
class Test
  def TestFunc(obj)
    puts obj
  end

  def Test.StatFun(obj)
    puts obj
    TestFunc(obj)
  end   
end

Test.StatFun([[5,2], [4,3]])
```

When I run this in `cmd.exe`, I get the following error:

> ruby LawtonTest.rb 5 2 4 3 LawtonTest.rb:10:in `StatFun': undefined
>   method`TestFunc' for Test:Class (NoMet hodError)
>           from LawtonTest.rb:14:in `'

I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have written an introduction to Ruby that might help you: http://www.apeth.com/rubyIntro/justenoughruby.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it on the object. I think you need a good reference of oop in Ruby, take a look at http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/oop/. But anyway, the thing is, methods (which is what you declare with `def`) have to be called on an object, not like a global function. So if you want to use `TestFunc`, try this:

```
def Test.StatFun(obj)
  puts obj
  Test.new.TestFunc(obj)
end
```

The `Test.new` part is used to create an object, on which you can use the `TestFunc` method.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the tutorial a look. I don't have a OOP background so so far ruby is very alien to me.

Comment: @conlaw: if you're coming from C or another procedural language, OOP is pretty hard. Just read the tutorial and search for others.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a definition for TestFunc anywhere. Have you defined it?

Also, the general Ruby convention is to use lowercase names for methods (eg `test_func`)

---

*edit* should really read the question before answering...

The problem here is that TestFunc is only defined for *instances* of the class Test, whereas when you call Test.StatFun, the object executing the code is the actual *class* Test. This means that it doesn't know what TestFunc is. One way to get around this is to create a new instance (because that is one thing classes do know how to do):

```
def Test.StatFun(obj)
  puts obj
  new.TestFunc(obj)
end
```